# What causes "CAdsWatchServerR0::AdsParseSymbol invalid array index"

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads

Since a week or so we have the following error popping up at our production machines:

```
CAdsWatchServerR0::AdsParseSymbol invalid array index!
```

The error are generated each plc cycle, filling up the windows event logger, because we forward the events:

[image]

The errors disappear after a reboot of the PLC, but after some time they reappear.

What is the cause of this error? And how can we locate its origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the Beckhoff support:

> In the new ADS *.dll the accesses via ADS are better monitored. This
> message means that you try to access an array index in the controller
> from a C# or other high level language via ADS, which is not
> available.
>
> Example: In the PLC project a `test :ARRAY[0..2] OF INT;` was defined. However, in the high-level language program you
> want to access e.g. `Test[3]`, which is not defined in the PLC.

In our case it turned out to be the HMI (TF2000). There was a user control in the HMI which had a symbol link to an array index which was no longer there.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I think it's great that you are sharing this knowledge, so that in case anyone else happens to have the same problem, they might find the answer here!